# Android Studio How do I stop my step counter value from resetting when I change fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm developing a step counter app with fragments. One fragment is the page for profile, the other fragment is where the step counter number shows. The issue that I'm having is that the step counter number will go up (for example 20 steps). When I click on the profile fragment and then go back to the step counter fragment, all those steps will then reset to zero. This is my code.

StepsFragment.kt

```
 private var sensorManager: SensorManager? = null

    private var running = false
    private var totalSteps = 0f
    private var previousTotalSteps = 0f

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_steps, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //sensor code
        sensorManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        loadData()
        resetSteps()
        loadPage()
    }

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        running = true
        val stepSensor = sensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)

        if(stepSensor == null){
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "there is no step sensor",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
        else{
            sensorManager?.registerListener(this, stepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI)
        }
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        if(running){
            totalSteps = event!!.values[0]
            val currentSteps = totalSteps.toInt() - previousTotalSteps.toInt()
            tvStepsTaken.text = ("$currentSteps")

            circularProgressBar.apply{
                setProgressWithAnimation(currentSteps.toFloat())
            }
        }
    }

    fun resetSteps() {
        tvStepsTaken.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Long tap to reset steps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        tvStepsTaken.setOnLongClickListener {
            previousTotalSteps = totalSteps
            tvStepsTaken.text = 0.toString()
            saveData()

            true
        }

    }

    private fun saveData() {
        val sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putFloat("key1", previousTotalSteps)
        editor.apply()
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        val sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedNumber = sharedPreferences.getFloat("key1", 0f)
        Log.d("StepsFragment", "$savedNumber")
        previousTotalSteps = savedNumber

    }
```

Is there something in the code that I am missing to prevent the step count from resetting whenever the fragment changes?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: since you are doing all the changes in `onResume()` and `onViewCreated()`, better to do initialization but whenever you are coming to this fragment. these two method is getting called and all the steps got resets.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the problem is about fragment transactions you use. If you use add,remove and replace when you change tab, your previous fragment is destroyed directly so when you back to this tab it is created again from nothing. To overcome this, (I assume that you want your counter works while a user at another tab) you should use show and hide for your fragments while switching between tabs.